# Return to command prompt when started mysql

Tags: mysql, linux, centos7

Is there a way in Centos7/Linux to return to the command line once you've started mysqld with the various config options? For me it just sits there and nothing I type/do will return to the command line.

Comment: Try ctrl-Z then `bg`

Comment: Just to confirm is bg a particular key combo? I have hit ctrl-Z and I then see ^Z in the output - I then type bg and still nothing. I'm using putty if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to put `&` character at the end of line.

For example, to start MySQL Server, run:

```
mysqld <options> &
```

The command above will allow you to run MySQL Server in background and you will be able to use the command line.

Comment: Superb - thanks for the advice and sorry for the delay in answering - I never saw I'd had an answer.